# How to extract loop conditions using Clang?

Tags: loops, parsing, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to extract loop conditions from the parse tree of a C program. I already have found the command to view abstract syntax tree (Parse tree) using Clang compiler. The command for viewing the parse tree is : `clang -Xclang -ast-dump filename.c`. Now , I want to extract loop conditions from this parse tree.

I have gone through various resources including search engines and user manual but I couldn't get a solution to this problem. Please, help me to resolve this.

For example, given the program:

```
void main()
{
    int a;
    while(a >10)
        a = a - 1;
}
```

the AST dump from Clang is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpjLh.png

The output should be `a >10`.

If the input program has two loops having conditions, then I want to extract both conditions.

I am not bothering about the language used by the extractor program. It would be good if it is available in C/C++.

Following is the portion of the image showing the loop condition a > 10 in AST.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Orc6K.jpg

Comment: Maybe post a simple program (with a loop) and its AST as an example.

Comment: This is the program that I have done.                                                                          void main()
{
        int a;
        while(a >10)
                a = a - 1;
}

Comment: Okay, so you should edit your question to: add that program, add the resulting AST dump from clang, and with reference to that example, clarify what you want to accomplish and where you're stuck.

Comment: Knowing where you're stuck is important to giving useful help. I can think of several ways you might be having trouble: understanding 'loop conditions', understanding ASTs in general, understanding clang's AST dump in particular, spotting loop conditions in the AST dump, devising a rule that characterizes/finds loop conditions in the AST dump, or writing a program to express that rule (extract the loop conditions).

Comment: I'm stuck in writing the program to express that rule (extract the loop conditions). Could you please help me to extract loop condition for the above program.

Comment: I have edited the question by attaching the images of code and generated AST as link. Kindly check it.  I don't know to extract loop condition from this code. Please, help me with it.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. However, Stack Overflow doesn't like (links to) images of text: links die, and people can't copy-paste text from an image. (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance on how to ask questions at Stack Overflow.) Also, both images are of the AST dump.

Comment: If you're stuck at writing the program to do the extraction, that suggests you're okay with the preceding steps. So, in words, what's your rule for finding loop conditions in the AST dump?

Also:
(1) What language should that extractor program be in? (I understand that the *input* program is in C, but that doesn't force the extractor program to be in C.)
(2) For the given example input program/AST, what should the corresponding output be?

Please edit your post to clarify these points.

Comment: I have edited the question.Please check it.

Comment: Okay, you changed one of the links, which is a slight improvement, but it's still unclear what your problem is. In my previous comment, I asked 3 questions; if you could edit your post to answer them, that might increase the chances that someone could help you.

Comment: I am not aware of any rule for finding loop conditions in the AST dump.

Comment: 1. My input program is in C. I am not bothering about the language used by the extractor program. It would be good if it is available in C/C++.

Comment: I am a beginner who is using Clang. I don't know whether there is any rule or something like that to extract loop conditions. I am trying to extract loop conditions and I just want to get loop conditions extracted from the program.

Comment: The program from which I want to extract loop conditions is given below :                void main()
{
        int a;
        while(a >10)
                a = a - 1;

}                                                                                                                                   This program contains a single while loop which contains a condition a < 10. I just want to extract this condition a < 10 from this program.

Comment: Thanks for answering those questions. I've edited your original post to incorporate your answers -- that's so that someone who's interested in helping only needs to look at the original post to get all the necessary info. (Note that the loop condition in your example program is `a >10`, not `i<10`.)

Comment: I'm getting a better idea of your difficulty, but still not sure. In the example AST dump, can you spot the portion that corresponds to the loop condition `a >10`?

Comment: I suspect the problem here is that Clang is very complex artifact, not well understood by OP.    Getting up the learning curve is likely to be a significant effort.   Is OP willing to make that investment?

Comment: Ignoring that, there's the question of just exactly what OP wants to extract:  the AST for the condition?  or the text string equivalent?    What will OP do with that information if extracted?  This will affect the answer.  If the AST is extracted, there's little one can do without using the Clang infrastructure for some further purpose.    If OP extracts the text string, how will that get used?  Finally, how will the loop containing the condition be associated/used with the answer?

Comment: Yes, I can spot the loop condition a > 10 in the generated AST. Iam attaching the image showing a > 10 in the post (which is marked).But actually my objective is just only to extract the loop condition a > 10 from the given program.  i.e., If we are giving a C program with loop as input, then I just want to get the extracted loop conditions as the output.

Answer (score 1):

OP>> *I am not bothering about the language used by the extractor program.*

OK, then Clang/C++ isn't a requirement for a solution.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](https://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) might be an answer.
(Not a C or C++ based tool; rather, DMS is a cooperating set of DSLs. See link for details).

DMS is a generalized compiler, configurable with arbitrary grammars and providing (among many other things) pattern-directed source code matching and transformation.   DMS has a robust C front end that can read many dialects of C, build ASTs, handle preprocessing directives, build symbol tables and control and data flow graphs.

Using DMS with its C front end, OP's example can be handled by providing a surface-syntax pattern to DMS:

```
domain C; -- specifies target language for patterns.
pattern while_condition(condition:expression,body:statement):statement
      = "while (\condition) \body;";
```

It should be obvious how to code patterns for other conditionals.

Writing patterns this way is much, much easier than writing tree-visiting code to look for individual nodes, by largely isolating the pattern writer from deep knowledge about the AST.

The named set of patterns is placed in an arbitrary file, e.g., `myPatterns.rsl`.

After parsing the C code and building the AST, DMS can be directed to search for that named pattern or an arbitrary set.   DMS will construct the AST for the *pattern* and use that to match against the target tree.  The metavariables `\condition` and `\body` will get bound to matching ASTs.   One can then use the rest of DMS to process the condition for any desired purpose, or to prettyprint the bound ASTs to produce the actual surface syntax text.

The (simplified) DMS code (in the PARLANSE DSL) to do this after DMS is configured to parse C code is:

```
(= my_tree (CDomain:Parse input_file_name))
(AST:ScanTree my_tree
              `Function applied to each visited AST node':
              (lambda (function boolean AST:Node)
                  (value (try `throw exception if no match':
                               (local (= [bindings RSL:Bindings]  
                                        (RSL:PatternMatch `the node':?
                                               `MyPatterns:while_condition'))=
                                   (CDomain:PrettyPrint bindings:1) ; \condition
                               )local
                               (acknowledge) ; catch no match exception, just ignore this node
                         )try
                         ~t ; continue scanning tree
                  )value
              )lambda ) ; AST:ScanTree
```

I suspect OP has some complicated issues not discussed.

1. If OP intends to export the conditional expressions, she probably wants to export the type information related to the operands of the expressions.   DMS and its C front can build full symbol tables (for C and other languages), and the identifiers found (by AST:Scan-ning the bindings) can be looked up to discover the actual type information.  One then needs a custom printing mechanism to print the types of those identifiers.
2. OP focused on loop conditions  However, there may be multiple conditionals between the function entry and the loop that control whether a loop gets executed at all.  If OP wants these, then DMS can provide an accurate control flow graph with control dependence information (see Wikipedia) so that conditionals preceding a loop can be enumerated.

A point to be made here is that "simple" extraction of program facts is often not that simple, and you'd like to have sufficient support machinery available to enable construction of the custom tool you need.   Thus the point of DMS.

The downside to DMS is that it takes a serious commitment to learn how to use it.  Learning how to use Clang (or any customizable program analysis tool) isn't much different in terms of effort on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Clang's AST dump (which I don't necessarily recommend), then...

- Scan through the dump for `WhileStmt` lines
  (i.e., lines where the first thing after spaces, vertical bars, and backticks is "-WhileStmt")
- Below the "W" of "WhileStmt", there is a column of vertical bars that ends with a backtick.
  On the lines where the vertical bar or backtick is followed by a "-",
  those lines represent a 'child' of the WhileStmt.

  Each WhileStmt will have 3 such children.
  The second one represents the loop condition.

  In the example, this line is

  ```
  |-BinaryOperator 0x55d984e526c0 <line:4:8, col:11> 'int' '>'
  ```

  (In practice, it will often say "BinaryOperator", but not always.)
- On that line, find the text delimited by angle brackets.
  In the example, this is

  ```
    <line:4:8, col:11>
  ```

  This conveys the textual extent of the loop condition.

  - The first part, `line:4:8`, means that the loop condition
    starts on line 4, at the 8th character.
    If you go back to the input program, line 4 is `while(a >10)`,
    and (assuming that the indentation is a single tab character)
    the 8th character is the `a`, as desired.
  - The second part, "col:11", means that the loop condition
    ends on the same line (line 4), at the 11th character.
    Going back to the input program, this is the "1" of the integer literal "10".
    So it's not actually the very end of the condition,
    but rather the start of the last token in the condition.
    (As far as I can tell, clang doesn't remember where tokens end.)

    (If the loop condition spans multiple lines, then the second part
    will look more like `line:5:10`, but you can interpret this in the same way
    as the first part.)
  - Knowing the start and end locations of the loop condition,
    you can go back to the input program and extract the text of the loop condition.

    The fact that the 'end' location is only the start of the final token
    means that you'll have to find the end of that token.

If you want to find loop conditions in statements other than `while` statements,
you can generalize the first 2 steps.

---

But I doubt that using Clang's AST dump is the easiest way to accomplish your goal.
E.g., you might be able to find a parser that remembers the ends of tokens/expressions.
And if you're willing to interact with an AST data structure rather than an AST dump,
that might make the code even simpler,
though it would probably be a steeper learning curve.